# Entity Framework Checking Date in Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, vb6

I am using Entity Framework in an ASP.Net MVC Project.  The point of the project was to create a web version of an existing older desktop project written in vb6.  This vb6 project saves dates as 11/11/1911 whenever a blank date is needed to the table because I have been told by the vb6 programmer that vb6 dates cannot be set to null.

Obviously in my classes I have dates such as:

```
public DateTime? ExampleDate { get;set; }
```

This causes the field to appear as 11/11/1911 when ideally it should be null and despite my insistence to change vb6 to simply null the dates the programmer is telling me it can't be done.  I know I can create manual properties in the class to check the field and return a value accordingly and mark it as [NotMapped] but there are a huge amount of dates across the tables and I don't want to be creating an extra property for every datetime nor do I want to be making a manual check in my code after loading a record and adding extra unnecessary code.

So what I would like to do if it's possible is somehow create my own datatype or method I can use in the class directly i.e. changing:

```
public DateTime? ExampleDate { get;set; }
```

To something like:

```
public CustomDateTime? ExampleDate { get;set; }
```

And have the CustomDateTime check and return accordingly.  Can anyone tell me if this is possible or recommend another solution?

EDIT: 
What about some kind of custom data attribute or similar?

```
[CustomDateTime]
public DateTime? ExampleDate { get;set; }
```

I tried with a custom validator but this only triggers on saving and I need to trigger the check when reading.

Comment: What is the database that you are using and what version?

Comment: You should be able to tackle this with a command tree interceptor. See an example [here](http://walkthetech.com/2015/05/31/implementing-soft-delete-in-entity-framework/).

Comment: @GertArnold Can you explain how to change this for my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't modify the DB to have meaningful values, a good idea might be to have a DataAccess Objet and a Business Object.

I'm using this answer as a reference, [How to map Data Access to Business Logic objects in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108846/how-to-map-data-access-to-business-logic-objects-in-entity-framework). He explains the idea very well.

This will add some complexity to your code but your entities will stay clean. And, if later the DB values are updated and '11/11/1911' is replaced by NULL you will just need to update your mapping.

Comment: It's already a huge amount of classes and data, this would take too long.

Comment: So you want a solution where you don't have to change anything?

Comment: I want a solution that is as simple as possible, yours is a good one I simply don't have the time to rewrite into two objects because of the scale of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend *not* adding additional fields for this purpose to your Entities, as you want to keep them clean.  If you're stuck with the values in your database representing what you would consider a `null` DateTime value then I would employ an extension method.

This way you don't have to repeat your code and you can keep your entities clean... something like this:

```
namespace Project.DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime? FromVb6DateTime(this DateTime? dateTime)
        {
            // Is the DateTime a VB6 null representation, if so, return null
            return (dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == "11/11/1911") ? dateTime : null;
        }
    }
}
```

The you can ensure that the values are converted to `null` under certain conditions:

```
// Using the extension namespace
using Project.DateTimeExtensions;

public class MyClass()
{
    public IDataService DataService;

    public MyClass(IDataService dataService)
    {
         this.DataService = dataService
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Get the date time value however you would normally
        var vb6DateTime = this.DataService.GetDate();

        // Convert the value using the extension method
        var convertedDateTime = vb6DateTime.FromVb6DateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you are thinking but this will mean doing what I was trying to avoid which was writing an extra line of code for each date I need to use.  If one table has 20 dates in it then that's twenty extra lines of code I need to get the converted date plus I am using WebApi which in most cases is simply returning the object i.e. return db.Students.AsNoTracking().Single(n => n.StudentId == id);